# RFC: @ syntax in TikZ path expression

Tags: tikz-pgf

I often encountered a situation, where I have a complex calculation in a path expression and want to go perpendicular down until I hit some line. For example:

```
\draw (node.30) -- (node.30 |- foo);
```

Now I have redundancy; if I change the outgoing degree, I have to edit two places. For more complex expressions this is cumbersome. Therefore, I propose an simple syntax to reference the last save position on a path:

```
\draw (node.30) -- (@ |- foo);
```

Here, the code and some small example. I would like to ask about your opinions, before I send it to the TikZ maintainers.

[image: Example Usage of @ synatx]

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}

% Define \pgfutil@at with the correct catcode
\expandafter\def\csname pgfutil@at\endcsname{@}

\makeatletter
% @ syntax to access last saved node on path
\let\tikz@parse@atsyntax@orig=\tikz@parse@node
\def\tikz@parse@node#1(#2#3){%
  \def\@next{\tikz@parse@atsyntax@orig#1(#2#3)}%
  % Is the name equal to '@'?
  \expandafter\ifx\pgfutil@at#2%
     \ifx#3&&%
         \edef\@next{\noexpand#1{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastxsaved}{\tikz@lastysaved}}}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \@next%
}%
\makeatother

% Example follows

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (A) {Text A};
    \node[draw] at (4,2) (B) {Text B};

    \draw[->] (A.east) -- ++(30:1cm)
        -- (@ |- B.west) % @ == ($(A.east)+(30:1cm)$)
        -- ($(@)!0.5!(B.west)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to just define a coordinate? All you need is `coordinate (a)` and then you can just use `a`. What happens when `@` is not a letter?

Comment: BTW, you can reuse the coordinate names.

Comment: Sure I could define a coordinate, but then I would have In the worst case N coordinate definitions before by path and the semantic relation between the path points would be less visible.

Comment: Why would you define them before rather than inline?

Comment: @JohnKormylo What did you have in mind?

Comment: @cft - coordinate(@) works.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You didn't ping right, but you mean rather than setting it as a special syntax, just use `coordinate (@)` on the path?

Comment: @cfr - Over and over again.

Comment: Will `($(A)!50!(@)$)` work?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually get away with an active character for this and you can turn on for some picture selectively.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{tilde is lastxy/.code={\def~{\csname pgf@x\endcsname,\csname pgf@y\endcsname}},
         reset tilde/.code={\def~{}}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[tilde is lastxy]
    \node[draw] (A) {Text A};
    \node[draw] at (4,2) (B) {Text B};
    \draw[->] (A.east) -- ++(30:1cm)
        -- (~ |- B.west) % @ == ($(A.east)+(30:1cm)$)
        -- ($(~)!0.5!(B.west)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]